# Integer.parseInt(String) throws a NumberFormatExpression

Tags: java, file, exception, javafx, integer

I'm reading in from a file that contains an item name and its quantity. I'm getting a `NumberFormatExpression` when I try to convert the quantity amount to an int. I feel it may be due to the `-` sign, but even after removing the `-` it stills throws the exception

```
String line = reader.readLine();

while (line != null) {
    String[] delimiter = line.split(",");
    int originalQuantity = Integer.parseInt(delimiter[1]);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

the file contents:

```
Toilet Papers, -10
Hand sanitizers, 12
```

Comment: A delimiter is the thing that indicates a break between two fields, in this case a comma.  String[] delimiter should be named differently, maybe something like String[] fields or String[] parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including a space at the beginning of the number. Use the [`trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()) method to get rid of it.

```
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    String[] delimiter = line.split(",");
    int originalQuantity = Integer.parseInt(delimiter[1].trim()); // <-- trim here
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```